# Launch JAR from vba script with JOptionPane

Tags: java, vba, jar, cmd

Are there any limitations in launching an executable JAR from a VBA script using `shell(...)`

My jar effectivly gets some IDs from the VBA script as launch arguments, queries values from a web service and displays them using `JOptionPane.ShowMessageDialog`

Here is my code:

```
private static JFrame quotenframe = new JFrame();
public static void main(String args[]){
    if(args.length < 3){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(quotenframe, "Not enough parameters!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        closeAll(1);
    }

    if(args[0].split("@").length<2){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(quotenframe, "Invalid value! '@' missing", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        closeAll(1);
    }
    String var1 = args[0].split("@")[0];
    String var2 = args[0].split("@")[1];
    String var3 = args[1];
    String var4 = args[2];

    String result = "";
    // Build resultString

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(quotenframe, result);

    closeAll(0);
}
```

The JAR itselfs executes without a problem when launched from a windows cmd shell, but when that same command line is run from the `Shell(...)` command in my VBA script, the only reaction is a java icon visible for a split second in the task bar, which then disappears.

My command is:
`java -jar jarFolder\myjar.jar param1 param2 param3`

and the execution directory is one level ontop of `jarFolder`.

It seems to me, that the JAR crashes upon launch, but, I cannot see why, as that same JAR, in the same directory, launched with the same command from a Windows shell works well.

Can it have anything to do with the `JOptionPane`? If not, any idea what the error could be?

Comment: What is the commanline command that you are issuing which works and what is the exact VBA command that you are using?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Edited to include the command. Thanks

Comment: it is just `shell("java -jar jarFolder\myjar.jar param1 param2 param3")`

Comment: If your folder path has spaces then you will have to pad that by double quotes...

Comment: Thanks, but I checked that. It does not contain spaces.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37724/discussion-between-luigiedlcarno-and-siddharth-rout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is, that you need to specify the full path to the jar, when invoking it using VBA's `Shell(...)` command, if the JAR is in a subfolder.